# Scanner Input is Invisible

Tags: java, debian, java.util.scanner, invisible

I have a Problem with the Scanner from Java. My Problem is, that I currently write a CloudSystem for Minecraft, and I code a Master and a Wrapper. On Wrapper the Scanner works perfectly, but on the Master not. The Problem is, that on the Master, the Input I write in the Console is not displayed, and I have to hit Enter twice, so the Scanner get the Input. The Code is on the Wrapper and the Master quite the same, just a few edits on the switch case. Also its a little bit strange, that it works on Windows but not on Debian.

Here is my Code:

```
public static void startScreen() {
    System.out.println(AnsiColor.GREEN + "Was moechtest du tun?");
    while (true) {
        String action = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        switch (action) {
            case "close":
                WebSocketServer.group.shutdownGracefully();
                shutdownServers();
                bcprocesse.destroy();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case "creategroup":
                createGroup();
                break;
            case "groups":
                Group.list();
                break;
            case "users":
                User.list();
                break;
            case "deletegroup":
                deleteGroup();
                break;
            case "help":
                help();
                break;
            case "createuser":
                createUser();
                break;
            case "deleteuser":
                deleteUser();
                break;
            case "request":
                System.out.println(AnsiColor.GREEN + "Welche Gruppe willst du benutzen? Es gibt: " + Group.getGroupsAsList().toArray().toString() + "\n");
                requestServer(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

P.S. Sorry when anything is not understandable, I'm from Germany.

Comment: You should probably initialize your `Scanner` only once, before the `while` loop .

Comment: how many scanners do you have in the other methods?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ In the other Methods I use 8 Scanner's + the one in the last case("request")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it... My problem was that I had started a Netty Server before and therefore I forgot to start it in a new Thread so it doesn't block the main Thread... Oops! I hope I could help other Devs with that, because sometimes.. you just don't think about situations like that.